# some details for the type vector<T,allocator<T>>

Tags: c++

In OpenCV, I always come across this type of variable `vector <T,allocator<T>>`.
Can someone explain to me what this mean in detail.

Comment: the type is : vector<T,allocator<T>>

Comment: Have you [read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)?

Comment: And [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays.

[image]

- **T**  -   The type of the elements.
- **Allocator**  -   An allocator that is used to acquire memory to store the elements. The type must meet the requirements of Allocator.